# Does $e^{i\theta}$ Relate To Hyperbolic Sine/Cosine?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, hyperbolic-functions

I would like to understand the relationship betwene $e^{i\cdot \theta}$ and hyperbolic sine and cosine. Here is what I have done so far:

Given:
$$\sinh(x)+\cosh(x)=e^x $$
$$i\sin(\theta)+\cos(\theta)=e^{i\theta} $$

Replaced $x$ in the first equation with $i\theta$ :

$$\sinh(i\theta)+\cosh({i\theta})=e^{i\theta} $$

Given:
$$i\sinh(x)= \sin(ix)$$
$$\cosh(x)=\cos(ix) $$
Replaced $x$ with $i\theta$ 
$$i\sinh({i\theta})= \sin(i\cdot{i\theta})=\sin(-\theta)$$
$$\cosh({i\theta})=\cos(i\cdot {i\theta})=\cos(-\theta) $$

$$\sinh(x)= \frac{\sin(ix)}{i}$$

I feel like I'm doing meaningless symbolic manipulation that likely is flawed on some level.

Comment: It only feels meaningless until you realise that all these functions are defined on $\mathbb{C}$, and not only on $\mathbb{R}$. Then you understand that these are fundamental identities.

Comment: You do know that $\sinh x = \frac12(e^x - e^{-x})$, right?

Comment: Now replace $x$ with $-i \theta$ and add the resulting equations. Don't forget that sine is odd and cosine is even!

Comment: @DanielFischer Thankyou for the encouragement.

Comment: @TheChaz2.0 I don't quite follow.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/455480/how-were-hyperbolic-functions-derived-discovered

Answer (score 2):

You could have obtained these identites a little easier using the definitions
$$\begin{align*}
\sin(x) & = \frac 1 {2i} (e^{ix} - e^{-ix}) \\
\cos(x) & = \frac 1 2 (e^{ix} + e^{-ix}) \\
\sinh(x) & = \frac 1 2 (e^x - e^{-x}) \\
\cosh(x) & = \frac 1 2 (e^x + e^{-x})
\end{align*}$$

As @DanielFischer said, these make much more sense when considered as whole functions on $\mathbb C$.

Comment: Does $x=\theta$ here?

Comment: @JoeHobbit $x\in\mathbb C$ is just _any_ variable. It can even be $\text{car}$, but noone wants to write
$$\sin(\text{car})$$
;-)

Comment: @AlexR That's indeed not a good name for a variable. Now $\sin (\text{bad})$, that makes sense.

Comment: @DanielFischer and $\sin(\text{good}) \approx \sin(\text{food})$?

Comment: It seems you missed the pun. You're not a seafarer, are you?

Comment: @DanielFischer Nope, neither mother tongue - it's easy to miss those puns then I guess :)