# Why do cosh and sinh determine the (x,y) coordinated of a unit hyperbola?

Tags: calculus, hyperbolic-functions

What exactly is the connection between the hyperbolic trig functions and the unit hyperbola, like in regular trigonometry where a right triangle can be placed onto the unit circle, how does this work for hyperbolic trigonometry?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_functions#/media/File:Hyperbolic_functions-2.svg

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/455480/how-were-hyperbolic-functions-derived-discovered