# Why are $\cosh$ and $\cos$ related by the imaginary unit?

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, conic-sections, hyperbolic-geometry

I'm interested, why are $\cosh$ and $\cos$ related by the imaginary unit like$$\cos (x)=\cosh (ix)?$$Is there any visual proof? How can be circle related to hyperbola by complex unit?

Comment: This is by definition, and by intent.  For $$x \in \Bbb{R}, ~: \cos(x) = \frac{e^{ix} + e^{-ix}}{2}.$$  Also, $\cosh(x)$ is defined to be $$\frac{e^{x} + e^{-x}}{2}.$$  Therefore, $$\cosh(ix) = \frac{e^{ix} + e^{-ix}}{2} = \cos(x).$$

Comment: This is not exactly what I wanted, so edited question. How can be something derived from circle changed by complex unit to make hyperbola?

Comment: It seems as if you are attempting to raise an interesting question.  Perhaps other reviewers will be able to perceive what you are trying to ask with respect to your references to a circle and a hyperbola.  Personally, I do not understand what you are trying to ask.  If no one else provides a helpful response to your posting, as is, then I will need you to be **much clearer** on what you are trying to ask.

Comment: @Adam How do you define $\cos x$ and $\cosh x $… that is the question?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net For his posting as is, except for the circle <--> hyperbola reference that I don't understand, then yes, that is the question.  However, my previous comment covered that, and the OP (i.e. original poster) indicated that he has a different question in mind.  The difficulty is, until he states his alternative question in much clearer detail, all that one can do is fall back on the definitions.

Comment: Maybe the better question would be is there any transformation that transform circle $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ into hyperbola $x^2 - y^2  = 1$?

Comment: Could you give me an example, in general, of what you have in mind by the term *transformation*?  Also, explanatory information belongs in the edited posting, not the comments.  Also, if you want a specific person to be flagged with a comment, you have to include the @... flag.

Comment: Something like linear transformation or Legendre transformation or involution - something that "stretches" circle to hyperbola.

Comment: I'm working on visualisation of "complex" rotation (rotation by complex angle).

Comment: @Adam Červenka: Just map $y\leftrightarrow iy$ will do.

Comment: Okey... So my last question when I rotate point $(0,1)$ by angle $\theta + i \phi, \theta, \phi \in R$, how would that point looks like after rotation?

Comment: In https://math.stackexchange.com/a/455625/35416 I'm relating the imaginary unit to alternating signs in the series expansion. It's not visual but perhaps it can be of some use. For rotation by a complex angle you would likely need 4d space to visualize this, since each complex-valued dimension would require 2 real-valued ones to depict. Perhaps you can find a nice projection to make that "only" 3d.